# Is there a way to automatically fill in array after getting user input?

Tags: cobol

I have an array of 5 elements and each of the elements holds a character. I want to accept user input in one line. For example: ABCDE. And I intend element 1 of the array to have A and element 2 of the array to have B and so on. Could someone help with this? I have attached the relevant portions of the code below:

```
environment division.
input-output section.
file-control.
    select standard-input assign to keyboard.
    select standard-output assign to display.

data division.
file section.
fd standard-input.
    01 stdin-record   pic x(80).
fd standard-output.
    01 stdout-record  pic x(80).

working-storage section.

    01  input-area.
        02 inputCharacters  pic x(1) occurs 5 times. 

    01  print-line.
        02 inputCharacters  pic x(1) occurs 5 times. 

procedure division.
    open input standard-input, output standard-output.

        read standard-input into input-area 
            at end
            close standard-input, standard-output
        end-read.

        write 
            stdout-record from print-line after advancing 5 line
        end-write

    stop run.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MOVE input-area TO print-line
```

For the code you have, you could also do this:

```
    write 
        stdout-record from input-area after advancing 5 line
    end-write
```

If you don't need two copies of a table (COBOL doesn't really have "arrays" in the way you're probably used to) then don't have two copies.

If you do have two tables, I'd suggest making the item names different. If you don't, you're making things tougher by having to use "qualification" to make the references unique.

```
MOVE inputCharacters ( 1 ) OF input-area 
                  TO inputCharacters ( 1 ) OF print-line
```

Instead of

```
MOVE inputCharacters ( 1 )  
                  TO outputCharacters ( 1 )
```

If you don't mind qualification yourself, you may find that colleagues or future maintainers hate it.

I'm not quite sure what you want to happen with this:

```
    read standard-input into input-area 
        at end
        close standard-input, standard-output
    end-read.
```

You only do one `read`, you you'll only get `at end` when there is no data (whatever that means with `keyboard`). In that case, you don't have data to do anything with.

You should look at how to use FILE STATUS for each file. Check the file-status field after each IO, and I'd also recommend using the file-status field for end-of-file checking, rather than the cumbersome AT END.

However, as I said, I don't know what that means with keyboard... so perhaps that won't work :-)

Comment: But does my read read the entire 5 characters entered and palce them each into one element? Do you know how this might be possible?

Comment: If the user has entered ABCDE and then pressed Return, then inputCharacters ( 1 ) should be A, ( 2 ) should be B, etc. If they've done A, Return, B, Return, etc, then No. ( 1 ) would have A and the rest would (probably) be space. Can't you experiment and answer that yourself?